# App crash on device after config iAD but not on simulator

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, iad

I am creating an app on cocos2d.
i config the iAd but I don't know my app is crashing on device but when I run app on simulator it works fine.

Error:

```
[ADBannerView initWithAdType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Code:

```
- (void)createAdBannerView {
    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (classAdBannerView != nil) {

        _adBannerView = [[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        [_adBannerView setPosition:ccp([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width/2, -33)];

        [_adBannerView setDelegate:self];

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:_adBannerView];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initWithAdType **requires** iOS 6.0 or above. If you are testing on an iOS 5.x device, you'll see the crash. Use the old way of initializing ADBannerViews (e.g., initWithFrame) on older devices.

This is the iOS 6.0 declaration for initWithAdType:

```
- (id)initWithAdType:(ADAdType)type __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_6_0);
```

To support the old iOS5 way of creating an iAd banner, you'll need to add:

```
#import <iAd/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h>
```

Example code:

```
ADBannerView *iAdView = nil;
if ([[ADBannerView class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) { // iOS 6.0
    iAdView = [[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner] autorelease];
} else { // iOS 4.x-5.x
    iAdView = [[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, appleWidth_, appleHeight_)] autorelease];
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = isLandscape_ ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using this way, but the below is the one mentioned in Apple's Documentation:

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
adView.delegate = self;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:adView];
```